# Import WinShell command not working in Python 3.3

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.3

I am using the following command for clearing the Recycle Bin in Python 3.3 using JetBrains Pycharm 5.0.1 IDE.

```
import winshell

winshell.recycle_bin().empty(confirm=False, show_progress=False, sound=False)
```

But I'm getting a **No module named winshell** error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install winshell
```

The module was missing, so you you must install it through pip (python package manager) using the -m flag which searchs for the specified program and executes his content ([src](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#interface-options))

Comment: Probably an explanation would help as well.

Comment: The module was missing, so he must install it through `pip` (python package manager) using the `-m` flag which searchs for the specified program and executes his content ([src](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#interface-options))

Comment: The comments come and go. Please, add this info to your answer by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52009576/edit).